# Trying to run chromedriver for Selenium results in errors

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image: Trying to run chromedriver for Selenium results in errors]

I used this code:

public class ChromeTest {

```
@Test
public void LaunchChrome_Method2() {        
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}
```

}

from this website:
http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-chromedriver/

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in your code. This can be fixed by the following:

1. Your filename is `Chrom.java` hence your public class name must be `Chrom` not `ChromeTest`.
2. Add import statements for `WebDriver` and `@Test` and `ChromeDriver`.

   ```
   import org.junit.Test;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
   ```